Encapsulation overlapping issue in Vlan Router settings. How do i solve it?
How my setting looks like in the picture

I use the gateway as the encapsulation for the router.
But everytime i try to add "Developer vlan" (Which in Norwegian is Utvikler)
Then i just get a overlapping error. What am i doing wrong?


edit: I figured out the issue. All i did was make the IP unique enough. And yes the broadcast was wrong for sure.
But i had on IT Drift Vlan 10 changed to
IP: 172.16.10.11
Subnett: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 172.16.10.1
and Utviklere Vlan 20 changed to
IP: 172.16.0.21
Subnett: 255.255.254.0
Gateway: 172.16.0.2
That did the trick more or less!
Appreciate the help either way!

Please add comments below the corresponding answer and not to your question. Also, please don't forget to vote for useful answer and to eventually accept an answer that was able to help you.

172.16.0.1/23 overlaps with 172.16.1.0/24 that is used for "IT-Drift". That is even the literal error message that you've cut off in your screenshot.
You need unambiguous subnets.
And btw: all your broadcast addresses noted in your diagram are incorrect. You might want to check out this excellent Q&A to brush up your subnetting skills.
